# How to create a R data.frame from string?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

While debugging code in R, I want to create a dataframe from a string like

```
"Column_A|Column_B
 Val-1|Val-2
 Val-3|Val-4"
```

I remember seeing a piece of code somewhere that does something like:

```
df <- some_function("input string")
```

but can't seem to remember the syntax

I do not want to take the approach of creating two separate vectors and create a dataframe from it like:

```
column_a <- c("Val-1", "Val-2")
column_b <- c("Val-3", "Val-4")
df <- data.frame(column_a = column_a, column_b = column_b)
```

Comment: `read.table(text = ...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `read.table`:

```
df <- read.table(text="
Column_A|Column_B
Val-1|Val-2
Val-3|Val-4", header=TRUE, sep="|")
```

Comment: Do you know how I can avoid extra spaces in the text? I end up doing an str_trim now.

Comment: Unless the extra spaces are consistently in the same place, triming after the data frame is constructed is usually the most straightforward open.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, we can also use `read.csv`

```
df <- read.csv(text = "Column_A|Column_B
                        Val-1|Val-2
                       Val-3|Val-4", sep = "|")

df

#  Column_A Column_B
#1   Val-1    Val-2
#2   Val-3    Val-4
```

Comment: The solution will work but all of that extra space to the left will be included as well. So instead of `df[1,1]` being "Val-1" it will be "[ ]+Val-1". `paste0()` or even `paste()` with the `sep = "|"` param will be cleaner.